# Как сделать новую колонку первой в PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я хочу добавить новую колонку в уже существующую таблицу и хочу что бы она была первой, в MySQL я использовал следующую команду:

```
ALTER TABLE my_contacts
    ADD COLUMN contact_id SERIAL NOT NULL FIRST,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (contact_id);
```

Но в PostgresSQL я получаю ошибку:

```
[42601] ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "FIRST") Позиция: 68
```

Comment: Никак. В постгрес нельзя так сделать. Увы. Только удалять таблицу и заново делать

Comment: К тому же порядок полей ни на что не влияет. Только лентяям плохо - приходится перечиcлять все поля в INSERT да SELECT...

Answer (score 1):

Дам отрывок [отсюда](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position/ru)

> Чтобы изменить порядок колонок, необходимо либо пересоздать таблицу,
> либо создать новые колонки с последующим переносом данных. Сама по
> себе идея перемещения колонок разработчикам PostgreSQL не претит,
> просто шаги к разработке данной функциональности не предпринимались.
> Назначение этого документа заключается в разъяснении обходных путей и
> тонких моментов, которые необходимо учитывать, при желании реализовать
> эту возможность.
>
> Существует две основные причины, по которым может понадобиться
> изменить порядок колонок в реалиях PostgreSQL:
>
> - размещение колонок фиксированной длины в начале таблицы влияет на    оптимизацию физической структуры
> - измененный порядок следования    колонок в результатах выборок может быть более привлекательным внешне
>
> На текущий момент PostgreSQL хранит порядок следования колонок таблиц
> к колонке attnum системной таблицы pg_attribute. Единственный путь
> изменить порядок колонки - пересоздать таблицу, или добавить колонки,
> переливая данные между старыми и новыми до тех пор, пока не будет
> достигнут нужный порядок.

Comment: AFTER я так понимаю что тоже нет?

Comment: @Петр Да вы правильно поняли. По факту добавляете в конец всегда. Чтоб получилось что нужно. Нужно устроить карусель с колонками. В нужном порядке